# python3 using pandas works on IDE but not in program

Tags: python, pandas

I get this error when I execute my code from the terminal:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Series'
```

from this code:

```
import pandas
numbers = {1,2,3,4,5}
ser = pandas.Series(list(numbers))
print(ser)
```

but the same code works fine from the IDE

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> numbers = {1,2,3,4,5}
>>> ser = pandas.Series(list(numbers))
>>> ser
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
```

sys.path:

```
['C:\\Users\\norman.khine\\Documents\\CodeCommit\\sysadmin\\scripts', 'C:\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36', 'C:\\Users\\norman.khine\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\whois-0.1-py3.6.egg']
```

all other modules import correctly!

Any help?

Comment: What is your script name? Or maybe some other script in that directory is named 'pandas.py'?

Comment: my script name is `ssl.py` and there is no pandas.py in my current directory

Comment: What does `print(pandas.__version__)` output?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the script name to something other than `ssl.py` resolved this.